# Angular 4, Hot module replacement appending instead of replacing

Tags: angular, webpack, hot-module-replacement

I'm having a weird issue, Hot module replacement has been working fine in my app for a while, but at some point recently, it has changed. Instead of replacing the specific component on the page, it is appending the component to the top of the page and still leaving a copy of the old component below.

I have searched all over google and also tried to figure out what has changed with very little luck. My WebPack file hasn't changed much at all.

Here is my [Webpack.js](https://gist.github.com/chriskooken/66a3970fc5a765a6b07f75ed9f09c639) file.

Angular 4

Visual Studio 2017

.Net Core 2.0

Comment: Odd. I've never heard of anything like this. I don't see anything wrong in your webpack config. I suggest doing a binary search to find what change caused it - go back to a commit where you know it worked, then pick a commit midway between then and now & see if it works there.... repeat until you find the commit that broke it. Unfortunately sometimes this is the only way.

Comment: If you're using the Angular / SPA template, do you have a boot.client.ts ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had this happen when using the .NET Core / Angular Template.  This snippet should ensure the old  component is removed and a new fresh one is created during the hot module replacement dispose hook.

If you have a boot.client.ts, see if it contains this:

```
if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept();
    module.hot.dispose(() => {

        // Before restarting the app, we create a new root element and dispose the old one
        const oldRootElem = document.querySelector('app');
        const newRootElem = document.createElement('app');

        oldRootElem!.parentNode!.insertBefore(newRootElem, oldRootElem);
        modulePromise.then(appModule => appModule.destroy());
    });
}
```

Comment: This was very close. I added a new Component at the root level of my app to handle routing to/from the login screen. It has a different name than 'app'. When I changed the code above to the new name, everything started working again.

Answer (score 1):

### **The accepted answer does not work with angular 5.**

After a couple hours I finally figured out a solution that worked for me.

First install @angularclass/hmr:

```
npm install --save-dev @angularclass/hmr
```

And then use this boot.browser.ts (some call boot.client.ts):

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
import 'zone.js';
import 'bootstrap';
import { enableProdMode, NgModuleRef, ApplicationRef } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module.browser';
import { createNewHosts } from '@angularclass/hmr';

const bootstrap = () => platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);

if (module.hot) {
    let ngModule: NgModuleRef<any>;
    module.hot.accept();

    bootstrap().then(mod => ngModule = mod);
    module.hot.dispose(() => {
        const appRef: ApplicationRef = ngModule.injector.get(ApplicationRef);
        const elements = appRef.components.map(c => c.location.nativeElement);
        const makeVisible = createNewHosts(elements);
        ngModule.destroy();
        makeVisible();
    });
} else {
    enableProdMode();
}
```

So far this has been working fine.